# How to get the Artboard with Nested Artboard in Flutter-Rive?

Tags: flutter, rive

I use the resource https://rive.app/community/1714-4322-rives-animated-emojis/, and i want to get one of them. I don't know how to get the Nested Artboard!

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if you found a solution for this already, but according to [this response](https://github.com/rive-app/rive-flutter/issues/193#issuecomment-1158134343) in [this Github issue](https://github.com/rive-app/rive-flutter/issues/193),

> to get the nested artboard to show through, you should instance the Artboard when you set it up with the Rive widget, so your setup would go from:

```
Rive(artboard: riveFile.artboardByName("artboard"));
```

> to

```
Rive(artboard: riveFile.artboardByName("artboard")!.instance());
```

more detail in the link. I hope this helps!

Edit: making it an answer

Comment: This is a comment not a answer!

Comment: Ohh got it, thanks, will change :)